# Given $C$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $C^3=0$, determine whether $C^2=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $C$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and $C^3=0$, determine whether $C^2$ is also $0$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be useful to tell us what you know and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi EuYu, I am a year 1 student from college and I have just finished a introductory linear algebra module. I know the basic ideas about determinant, eigenvalue, etc... The problem is that I am not familiar enough to use these ideas effectively. From this question I can see that det(C)=0, am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for giving your background. Given your background you might not understand the minimal polynomial based argument given by Easy below. If you know about the Cayley-Hamilton theorem then that's one way to proceed. The fact that the determinant is $0$ is good but it is not enough in this case. There are many matrices which do not satisfy this property but still have determinant $0$. Are you able to figure out the eigenvalues of the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: First determine the eigenvalues of $C$. Then think about Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that 0 is the only eigenvalue of C, then $a=-d$ and $bc = -a^2$ and it follows that $C^2=0$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The minimal polynomial of $C$ has degree at most $2$.

Comment: Thanks as well, though I haven't learnt about this minimal polynomial yet. :)

Answer (score 4):

If $C^3=0$ but $C^2\neq0$, then there must be a vector $v$ such that $C^2(v)\neq0$ but of course $C^3(v)=0$. Now consider the vectors $v,C(v),C^2(v)$. Try to show successively that $(C^2(v))$, $(C^2(v),C(v))$ and $(C^2(v),C(v),v)$ are linearly independent. For instance for the second step, if $C(v)=aC^2(v)$ for some scalar $a$, then applying $C$ to both sides one gets $C^2(v)=0$ which contradicts the linear independence of $(C^2(v))$. But $(C^2(v),C(v),v)$ being linearly independent in dimension $2$ is absurd.